# React native upgrade to .69 from .64

Tags: ios, react-native

I had to update to the most recent version of react native for my project. But no matter what iu do I can't get this error to go away on IOS ONLY. Android works fine even though this error is mostly reported as a android issue.

ERROR  Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument.

I have updated every package that is possible cleared all caches etc etc.

Here is the package list.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@freakycoder/react-native-helpers": "^1.0.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.8",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "git+https://github.com/react-native-toolbar-android/toolbar-android.git#master",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/elements": "^1.3.4",
    "@react-navigation/routers": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.2",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.6",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.6",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^5.0.0-alpha.1",
    "@sergiorj/react-native-snap-carousel": "^4.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-sym": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "main": "^1000.0.1",
    "os": "^0.1.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.69.3",
    "react-native-awesome-alerts": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-charts-wrapper": "^0.5.9",
    "react-native-clean-project": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-codegen": "^0.71.0",
    "react-native-config": "^1.4.6",
    "react-native-copilot": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-crypto": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-default-preference": "^1.4.4",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.0.2",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-dynamic-vector-icons": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.5.11",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-image-slider-box": "^1.1.24",
    "react-native-improved-text-input": "0.0.1",
    "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn": "^3.7.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-randombytes": "^3.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.9.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.15.0",
    "react-native-shared-preferences": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-spinkit": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.4.3",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "git+https://github.com/wymsee/react-native-swipe-gestures.git#master",
    "react-native-tracking-transparency": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.23.0",
    "react-style-proptype": "^3.2.2",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "uuid": "^7.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.18.9",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.70.3",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "platform": "^1.3.5",
    "prettier": "2.4.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.5.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.0.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.5",
    "yargs": "^17.5.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
```

Comment: You should at least put in the effort to format that. It's totally unintelligible.

Comment: @Alexander I apologize it was formatted when i pasted it, I didn't realize i needed to surround with the backticks.

Comment: much better! There's a higher chance now that people will approach this question and try to answer you :)

Comment: have you solved it?

Comment: i solved it by downgrading, some of the packages just were not compatible